# Can I get my own exposure notification app approved for the App Store?

Tags: ios, ios-appstore

I have an app that reports the results of rapid SARS-CoV-2 nucleic acid tests and would like to automate the process of propagating the results of that test through the Apple/Google [Exposure Notification API](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/exposurenotification). Can I add exposure notifications to my app, or is it only possible for *one* app per region to get App Store approval?

Comment: Are you intending to use this API? https://www.apple.com/covid19/contacttracing/ it’s not clear if you’re just pushing a normal app or utilizing contact tracing. The second requires a lot of extra requirements over the normal approval process. What’s the harm submitting your app for review?

Comment: @bmike Using Apple's API; [clarified](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/399628/revisions)

Answer (score 2):

According to [Apple's Exposure Notification API Addendum](https://developer.apple.com/contact/request/download/Exposure_Notification_Addendum.pdf) to the Developer Program License, you need the Exposure Notification Entitlement Profile.

To get that entitelment, it states:

> **2.  Entitlement Request; License and Restrictions**
>
> 2.1 In order to use the Exposure Notification APIs, You must be a government entity, such as a government health services organization, or a developer who has been endorsed and approved by a government entity to develop an Application on behalf of a government for COVID-19response efforts.

Unless you are part of an authorized government agency, you will not be able to get this entitlement or submit an app.

Answer (score 0):

As described in the [FAQ](https://covid19-static.cdn-apple.com/applications/covid19/current/static/contact-tracing/pdf/ExposureNotification-FAQv1.1.pdf):

[image]

So you need to get involved with the public health authorities in your region to proceed on that. Uploading positive test results is a tightly controlled process step (for obvious reasons as it would be rather easy to break the system if anybody can upload positive results at will).